# IonicTimePicker not displaying in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic Time PIcker that is not displaying in my phone.I'm not sure what I'm missing from the code that is not displaying the time picker. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Missing TimePicker]

As you can see from the image above, the timepicker is missing. Below are my codes.

TimePicker.js

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.service')
    .factory('TimePicker', TimePicker);

    TimePicker.$inject = ['ionicTimePicker'];
    function TimePicker(ionicTimePicker){
        return {
            openTimePicker: openTimePicker
        };

        function openTimePicker(time, cb){
            var arg = {
                callback: function(hour, minute){
                    cb(angular.copy(time).hour(hour).minute(minute));
                },
                inputHour: time.hour(),
                inputMinute: time.minute(),
            };
            ionicTimePicker.openTimePicker(arg);
        }
    }

})();
```

createController.js

```
function openTimePicker(type){
        if(type === 'start'){
            TimePicker.openTimePicker($scope.eventCreate.startDate, _.partial(datePickerCb, 'start'));
        }else if(type === 'end'){
            TimePicker.openTimePicker($scope.eventCreate.endDate, _.partial(datePickerCb, 'end'));
        }
    }
    function datePickerCb(type, date){
        if(type === 'start'){
            $scope.eventCreate.startDate = date;
        }else if(type === 'end'){
            $scope.eventCreate.endDate = date;
        }
    }
```

timepicker.html

```
 <div class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Start Time</span>
                <div class="input-time-container">
                    <span class="input-date" ng-click="openDatePicker('start')">{{eventCreate.startDate.format('D MMM YYYY')}}</span>
                    <span ng-hide="eventCreate.allday" ng-click="openTimePicker('start')" class="input-time">{{eventCreate.startDate.format('H:mm A') }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-input" ng-hide="eventCreate.allday" ng-class="{invalid: (eventCreate.endDate.hour() * 60 + eventCreate.endDate.minute() < eventCreate.startDate.hour() * 60 + eventCreate.startDate.minute())}">
                <span class="input-label">End Time</span>
                <div class="input-time-container">
                    <span ng-click="openTimePicker('end')" class="input-time">{{eventCreate.endDate.format('H:mm A') }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why are using that? For some specific reason? Take a look to this: http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/#date

Comment: I did come across this but it does not have the display of the time picker.  I wanted to keep the timepicker in a modal window hence i opted for the other approach.